# dynamic amount of threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, dynamic, c++11

My task is to sort N tables of integers. Each table I read from file and store in an array. 
I'd like to create program where user choose how many threads should sort that all tables(one table for each thread). I don't know how to do resolve situation when I have for example use 4 threads and have 11 arrays to sort.

my code(not proper):

```
#include <thread>
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfThreads; i++)
{
    listOfThreads[i] = thread();
}
// ...

while (!listOfArraysToBeSort.empty())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfThreads; i++)
    {
        if (i>amountOfThreads) i = 0;


        thread t1( listOfArraysToBeSort[index2]);
        listOfThreads.push_back(t1);
        listOfArraysToBeSort.erase(listOfArraysToBeSort.begin()+index2);
        index2++;

    }           

    thread t1(&ArrayToBeSort::startASM, &listOfArraysToBeSort[index2]);
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `ArrayToBeSort::startASM`, what are your particular problems? You resized `listOfThreads` properly, before populating it?

Comment: You could refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961899/thread-pool-and-execution-queue-in-c11 for thread pool.

Comment: startASM do : open file with numbers, load it to array and sorts it using DLL written in assembler. 
vector<thread> listOfThreads (amountOfThreads);

Answer (score 0):

You can split your threads by packs: if you have 5 threads and 11 arrays then you will process 5, 5 and 1 threads.
Here is a sample code that does it.

i don't have files, I generate data on the fly but this part is separated from the sorting part so no possible confusion

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include  <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int generateData(vector<vector<int>>& vData)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 1000000);
    const int nbElemsPerVec=1000000;
    int nbArray;
    cout<<"How many arrays" << endl;
    cin >> nbArray;

    for (int i=0;i<nbArray;++i)
    {
        vector<int> vArr;
        for (int j=0; j<nbElemsPerVec; ++j)
        {
            vArr.push_back(dis(gen));
        }
        vData.push_back(vArr);
    }

    return 0;
}

int sortData(vector<vector<int>>& vData, int nbThreads)
{
    vector<thread> vThreads;
    int nbArray=vData.size();
    int nbArrayPerThread=nbArray/nbThreads+1;
    for (int i=0;i<nbThreads;++i)
    {
        vThreads.push_back(
        std::thread ([i, nbArrayPerThread,nbArray,&vData]{
        for (int j=0;j<nbArrayPerThread;++j)
        {
            if (i*nbArrayPerThread+j < nbArray)//to avoid out of bounds exception
            {
                std::sort(vData[i*nbArrayPerThread+j].begin(),(vData[i*nbArrayPerThread+j].end())); 
            }
        }
        })
        );
    }

    for (auto it=vThreads.begin(); it!=vThreads.end();++it)
    {
        it->join();
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int nbArray,nbThreads;
    vector<vector<int>> vAllData;//array of vectors to be sorted out
    generateData(vAllData);
    nbArray=vAllData.size();
    cout <<"How many threads"<<endl;
    cin>>nbThreads;
    nbThreads=min(nbThreads,nbArray);
    sortData(vAllData,nbThreads);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps, ask me if you have any questions (I can detail more some parts)